# Programming in Visual C++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, forms

I am new to this Development tool and i want to develop an application for my project in which i need a GUI which will get the values from a user and these values will be used by my program to show an output
So this is what i want:

1.Can i use Visual Studio forms for front end 
 if so how do i send the values from forms to my program

2.How to get the values from the text boxes 
  ?=textBox1->Text; what should the variable be in "?" and what is the type of variable

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             =textBox1->Text;
         }
```

i want the values into an integer how do i do it

Comment: Please read a tutorial, answering this exact question will just bring up the next.

Comment: You can use Forms, but you have to be *a lot* more specific on what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes you can use VStudio Forms for front end. You have not given much details about your other program. I would say, if you want to pass some values between programs, there are multiple ways.

   A) Commandline arguments.

   B) Store the values in a file and other program would read the file.

   C) Inter-process communication - Memory mapped files can be used.

   D) Sockets also can be used if both the program are running simultaneously.
2. You can get the value from text box in a String type variable as below

   ```
   System::String^ s =textBox1->Text;
   ```

   You can convert the value to any other numeric type as below -

   ```
   Int16 intValue = Convert::ToInt16(s);
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the reply 
I was actually looking for something like this only 
Could you help me with tutorials for the Command line arguments please